# Get few columns from another table withou other entity by foreign key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, entity

Is it possible in hibernate to join only few columns from other primary table in one entity of secondary table without entity of the primary table? So i want to create entity of secondary table from sql query like this:

```
select secondary.*, primary.column1
from secondary_table as secondary
join primary_table as primary on primary.id = secondary.id_primary
```

So i have all columns from secondaryTable and column1 from primaary table joined by column id_primary from secondary table, i dont want to create primary table entity.

*edit

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="secondary_table")
    public class SecondaryTable{
    
        @Id     @SequenceGenerator(name="secondary_table_id",sequenceName="secondary_table_id_seq",allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator="secondary_table_id")
        @Column(name="id",nullable=false)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name="column1_from_secondary_table",nullable=false)
        private Long column1ST;
    
        @Column(name="column2_from_secondary_table",nullable=false)
        private Long column2ST;

        @Column(name="id_to_primary_table",nullable=false)
        private Long idPrimaryTable;

/*i want only this column from primary table in my secondary table entity where idPrimaryTable = id from primary Table and i dont want PrimaryTable ENtity*/
        @Column(table = "primary_table", foreignKey = "id_primary_table",name="column1_from_primary_table",nullable=false)
            private Long column1PT;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only parts of an entity your best bet is usually to use DTOs. Not sure if you know what the term "secondary table" exactly means in JPA, but I assume you do not and simply want a certain extra column. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(SecondaryTable.class)
public interface SecondaryTableDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    Long getColumn1ST();
    Long getColumn2ST();
    @Mapping("primaryTableAssociation.column1PT")
    Long getColumn1PT();

    // If you don't have a primaryTableAssociation you can use this

    // @Mapping("PrimaryTable[id = VIEW(idPrimaryTable)].column1PT")
    // Long getColumn1PT();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`SecondaryTableDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, SecondaryTableDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<SecondaryTableDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: i dont see where i can set name of the primary table. How it will know from which table it will take the column1PT?

Comment: You need an entity for that table similar to your `SecondaryTable` called i.e. `PrimaryTable`. If you add an `@ManyToOne` association mapping from `SecondaryTable` to `PrimaryTable` you can use the first mapping and if you don't have/want that, you can use the second kind of mapping which will create a join for you behind the scenes. Try it out and you will see what query is generated.

Comment: but i want to add column from another table without creating additional entity

Comment: In that case you need the `@SecondaryTable` annotation but note that this has to be a one-to-one relation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html

Comment: can i use somehow SecondaryTable annotation in entity  with foreign key to my primary table?

Comment: No, that would be a many-to-one association for which you need to map the other table as entity.

Comment: so there is no way to add only one column to entity by foreign key from another table without additional entity?

Comment: Well you can use `@Formula("(select col from other_tbl where fk = id)")` if you really want that, but that is not updatable, just read only.

Comment: i dont need to update this column, so when i want second column from primary table then i need use additional formula for next table so there will be executed two separate selects ?

Comment: No, this formula is executed as subquery as part of the query that fetches the entity.